# joomla php notice error of only variable should be passed in

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

Hi Getting php notice error of only variable should be passed in

```
    $this->assignRef('CatList'  , $modelUsedcar->loadMainCat($brand,$Carmodel));
```

Can anyone suggest on how to make this function better for php 8.0 & joomla 3.10 standards and remove error

```
class UsedcarViewCategory extends JViewLegacy
{
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $mainframe =JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
        $db         =   JFactory::getDBO();
        $user               = JFactory::getUser();
        $model              = $this->getModel();
        $modelUsedcar   = $this->getModel( 'category' );            
        $brand = JRequest::getVar('brand','','default','int');
        $Carmodel = JRequest::getVar('model','','default','int');
        $id = JRequest::getVar('id','','default','int');    
        $this->assignRef('CatList'  , $modelUsedcar->loadMainCat($brand,$Carmodel));
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake as catlist was not defined
Its solved

```
$CatList = $modelUsedcar->loadMainCat($brand,$Carmodel);
        $this->assignRef('CatList'  , $CatList);
```

Comment: Hi @Ruchika if you have resolved your issue please be sure to mark your question as answered in order to help keep orphaned questions at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the "Only variables should be passed by reference" notice and make the code compliant with PHP 8.0 and Joomla 3.10 standards, you can modify the code as follows:

```
class UsedcarViewCategory extends JViewLegacy
{
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $this->get('Option'); // Recommended way to retrieve the component option
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $model = $this->getModel();
        $modelUsedcar = $this->getModel('category');
        $brand = $this->input->getInt('brand'); // Updated method to retrieve request variable as an integer
        $Carmodel = $this->input->getInt('model'); // Updated method to retrieve request variable as an integer
        $id = $this->input->getInt('id'); // Updated method to retrieve request variable as an integer

        $CatList = $modelUsedcar->loadMainCat($brand, $Carmodel); // Assign to a variable instead of using assignRef

        $this->assign('CatList', $CatList); // Use assign instead of assignRef
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```